# String template for Database only taking last part

Tags: javascript

I don't see it, what am I missing here?  `count` is an incoming param to my method.

```
const allFields = `
  select 
  company_id,
  company_name
  from company
`;
```

Then:

```
const query = `${allFields} ORDER BY company_created_date DESC ` && count > 0 ? 'LIMIT' : '';
```

I'm only getting the text 'LIMIT' back for the query.  At the least I should get the first part  `${allFields} ORDER BY company_created_date DESC`

Comment: ```
const query = `${allFields} ORDER BY company_created_date DESC ${count > 0 ? `LIMIT ${count}` : ''}`;
```

Comment: Are you trying to add `LIMIT` to the end of the query when `count > 0`? You need to use concatenation, not `&&`.

Comment: yea trying to append LIMIT on.  First I tried to do it all within `` but no luck first time.  What do you mean specifically by concat, which technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` is not the concatenation operator, but it looks like you're trying to concatenate to the end of the query. Concatenation is done using `+`.

And you should put parentheses around the ternary. It has low precedence, so the addition expression will otherwise be considered the condition.

```
const query = `${allFields} ORDER BY company_created_date DESC ` + (count > 0 ? `LIMIT ${count}` : '');
```

Comment: ah that's what I was missing.  I had tried `+` but didn't put () around the JS.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
const query = `${allFields} ORDER BY company_created_date DESC ` && count > 0 ? 'LIMIT' : '';
```

is being parsed as:

```
if(`${allFields} ORDER BY company_created_date DESC`  && count > 0){
    query = 'LIMIT';
} else {
    query = '';
}
```

basically the string part is always `true` so if count is larger than 0 youll get `'LIMIT'`, otherwise `''`

if I get what you were going for, try this:

```
const query = `${allFields} ORDER BY company_created_date DESC ${count > 0 ? 'LIMIT' : ''}`;
```